# CakePHP 2 How to pass variables through the URL when using pagination?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a project in CakePHP application and I want to add pagination to it. I have added pagination to it, but when I click on a page number or go to the next page my application breaks.

The page relies on variables being passed to the controller in order to display the correct data. Here is my code for the view:

```
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Job ID</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Site</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($data as $jobsheet) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $jobsheet['Jobsheet']['jobnum']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo date("l, jS F Y", strtotime($jobsheet['Jobsheet']['jobdate'])); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="companyname"><strong><?php echo $jobsheet['Siteaddress']['sitename'] ?></strong></span><br />
                            <?php echo $jobsheet['Siteaddress']['addressline1']; ?>, 
                            <?php echo $jobsheet['Siteaddress']['addressline2']; ?>, 
                            <?php if ( $jobsheet['Siteaddress']['addressline3'] = '') { ?>
                                <?php echo $jobsheet['Siteaddress']['addressline3']; ?>, 
                            <?php } else { ?>

                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php echo $jobsheet['Siteaddress']['city']; ?>, 
                            <?php echo $jobsheet['Siteaddress']['county']; ?>, 
                            <?php echo $jobsheet['Siteaddress']['country']; ?>, 
                            <?php echo $jobsheet['Siteaddress']['postcode']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#viewjobsheet<?php echo $jobsheet['Jobsheet']['id']; ?>" onClick="document.getElementById('jbif<?php echo $jobsheet['Jobsheet']['id']; ?>').src='/modal/customers/<?php echo $company['Company']['id']; ?>/jobs/<?php echo $jobsheet['Jobsheet']['id']; ?>/view/';" title="View" class="icon-eye-open"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?> 

        <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
    <br />
    <br />
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
                'format' => 'Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of
                         {:count} total, starting on record {:start}, ending on {:end}'
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller:

```
function index(){

    $companyid = $this->params['customer'];
    $this->set('companyid', $companyid);
    $siteid = $this->params['site'];

    $this->loadModel('Jobsheet');

    // Job Sheets
    $jobsheets = $this->Jobsheet->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Jobsheet.company' => $companyid), 'recursive' => 2, 'order' => 'Jobsheet.jobdate DESC', 'limit' => '10'));
    $this->set('jobsheets', $jobsheets);

    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 10
    );

    $data = $this->paginate('Jobsheet');
    $this->set(compact('data'));    

}
```

While the pagination does work, it ends up loosing the variable and this breaks what I'm trying to do. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `PaginatorHelper::options` (see the [API](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelperoptions))

For example, say we want to pass the variable `$pass` between Paginator page changes.  So first pass the variable to the `View`.

```
public function index() {
    $pass = 'testString';
    $this->set(compact('pass'));
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
}
```

In the `View`, we can then add this to the parameters that Paginator passes when changing pages using `Paginator::options` and the `url` option.

```
<?php
    $this->Paginator->options(array(
        'url' => array(
            'pass' => $pass
        )
    ));
?>
```

So if you moved from page 1 to page 2, the resulting url would be something similar to:

```
http://localhost/cake/posts/index/pass:testString/page:2
```

This is also how Paginator passes sort orders and sort keys.  So while "pass" in `pass:testString` can be anything you want, be sure not to use `sort`, `direction`, and `page`.

As long as you are changing pages through the Paginator links, the passed variables will remain.  Note that you can access the values of the passed arguments in both the `View` and the `Controller` by the property:

```
$this->passedArgs
```